# Regular expression for numeric range from -a to b where a is not equal to b

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Let `a` and `b` be digits. The problem is easily solved if a=b, I can test the sign/no sign and then proceed to match the range of numbers from 0-a. I don't know how to solve this when the numbers are unequal.

How can I do it in python using a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

If you want for example between -7 and 4 :
`(-[1-7]|[0-4])`

Here is an example : https://regex101.com/r/8TnSVn/1

Comment: Maybe, it will be better: `(-[1-7]|[0-4])`.  `-0` is not a correct expression.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Due to that comment a bug was found and a discussion appeared :-) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355838/what-is-technically-forbidden-in-the-comment

Comment: [Missing some anchors maybe... ;)](https://regex101.com/r/8TnSVn/4)